# Istanbul is not generating the coverage for mocha chai and chai-http test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, istanbul

I am trying to generate istanbul code coverage for my api.I have looked into many answers in SO and also the doc of istanbul but nothing is working for me. mocha tests are running fine and everything is getting passed, even istanbul is creating the **coverage** folder also, but it is not creating the report within it.My app is simple express app and I am using chai,chai-http and mocha for it. below is my code for **test/app.js** file and **package.json** file.

```
const app=require('../app');
const chai=require('chai');
const chaiHttp=require('chai-http');
const should=chai.should();
const tokenForToday="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6ImFudXJhbmJhcm1hbkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE1MTc1Mzg4ODcsImV4cCI6MTUxNzYyNTI4N30.8YJ35mwWhzz4kT-fruhcPANUXyZJYvCsKKHTejZNnWA";
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('CB API',()=>{
    /**
     * Test /api route
     */

    describe('/GET api',()=>{
      it('it should GET the api default content', (done) => {
      chai.request(app)
          .get('/api')
          .end((err, res) => {
              res.should.have.status(200);
              res.body.should.be.eql({message:'Welcome to Cloudboost API'});
            done();
          });
      });
    })

    /**
     * Test /login POST route
     */
     describe('/POST login',()=>{
       it('it should return the authentication token', (done) => {
         let bdy={
           email:"anuranbarman@gmail.com",
           password:"anuran"
         }
       chai.request(app)
           .post('/api/login')
           .send(bdy)
           .end((err, res) => {
               res.should.have.status(200);
               res.body.should.have.property('token');
               res.body.should.have.property('auth').eql(true);
             done();
           });
       });
     })

     /**
      * Test /login POST without email field
      */
      describe('/POST login',()=>{
        it('it should return false success', (done) => {
          let bdy={
            password:"anuran"
          }
        chai.request(app)
            .post('/api/login')
            .send(bdy)
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(422);
                res.body.should.have.property('auth').eql(false);
              done();
            });
        });
      })

      /**
       * Test /image route without token
       */
       describe('/POST image without token',()=>{
         it('it should return false success', (done) => {
           let bdy={
             url:"https://d1qb2nb5cznatu.cloudfront.net/startups/i/490103-917cc2864d0246e313e9521971422f09-medium_jpg.jpg?buster=1430997518"
           }
         chai.request(app)
             .post('/api/image')
             .send(bdy)
             .end((err, res) => {
                 res.should.have.status(401);
                 res.body.should.have.property('success').eql(false);
               done();
             });
         });
       })

       /**
        * Test /image with token but with invalid url
        */
        describe('/POST image with invalid url',()=>{
          it('it should return false success', (done) => {
            let bdy={
              url:"https://d1qb2nb5cznatu.cloudfrt.net/startups/i/490103-917cc2864d0246e313e9521971422f09-medium_jpg.jpg?buster=1430997518"
            }
          chai.request(app)
              .post('/api/image')
              .set('token',tokenForToday)
              .send(bdy)
              .end((err, res) => {
                  res.should.have.status(500);
                  res.body.should.have.property('success').eql(false);
                done();
              });
          });
        })

        /**
         * Test /image with token but with NO url
         */
         describe('/POST image with no url',()=>{
           it('it should return false success', (done) => {

           chai.request(app)
               .post('/api/image')
               .set('token',tokenForToday)
               .end((err, res) => {
                   res.should.have.status(422);
                   res.body.should.have.property('success').eql(false);
                 done();
               });
           });
         })

         /**
          * Test /image with token and with valid url
          */
          describe('/POST image',()=>{
            it('it should return false success', (done) => {
              let bdy={
                url:"https://d1qb2nb5cznatu.cloudfront.net/startups/i/490103-917cc2864d0246e313e9521971422f09-medium_jpg.jpg?buster=1430997518"
              }
            chai.request(app)
                .post('/api/image')
                .set('token',tokenForToday)
                .send(bdy)
                .end((err, res) => {
                    res.should.have.status(200);
                  done();
                });
            });
          })


          /**
           * Test /image with invalid token but with valid url
           */
           describe('/POST image',()=>{
             it('it should return false success', (done) => {
               let bdy={
                 url:"https://d1qb2nb5cznatu.cloudfront.net/startups/i/490103-917cc2864d0246e313e9521971422f09-medium_jpg.jpg?buster=1430997518"
               }
             chai.request(app)
                 .post('/api/image')
                 .set('token','tokenForToday')
                 .send(bdy)
                 .end((err, res) => {
                     res.should.have.status(500);
                     res.body.should.have.property('success').eql(false);
                   done();
                 });
             });
           })

           /**
            * Test /patch with token and data and patch
            */
            describe('/PATCH patch',()=>{
              it('it should return success', (done) => {
                const dataString=JSON.stringify({
                        name: "dante",
                        age: "22"
                });
                const patchString=JSON.stringify([
                  { "op": "replace", "path": "/name", "value": "anuran" },
                  { "op": "add", "path": "/position", "value": "NodeJS Developer" }
                ])
                let bdy={
                  data:dataString,
                  patch:patchString
                }

              chai.request(app)
                  .patch('/api/patch')
                  .set('token',tokenForToday)
                  .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
                  .send(bdy)
                  .end((err, res) => {
                    console.log(res.body);
                      res.should.have.status(200);
                      res.body.should.have.property('success').eql(true);
                    done();
                  });
              });
            })


            /**
             * Test /patch without token
             */
             describe('/PATCH patch',()=>{
               it('it should return false success', (done) => {
                 const dataString=JSON.stringify({
                         name: "dante",
                         age: "22"
                 });
                 const patchString=JSON.stringify([
                   { "op": "replace", "path": "/name", "value": "anuran" },
                   { "op": "add", "path": "/position", "value": "NodeJS Developer" }
                 ])
                 let bdy={
                   data:dataString,
                   patch:patchString
                 }

               chai.request(app)
                   .patch('/api/patch')
                   .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
                   .send(bdy)
                   .end((err, res) => {
                     console.log(res.body);
                       res.should.have.status(422);
                       res.body.should.have.property('success').eql(false);
                     done();
                   });
               });
             })


             /**
              * Test /patch without data field
              */
              describe('/PATCH patch',()=>{
                it('it should return false', (done) => {

                  const patchString=JSON.stringify([
                    { "op": "replace", "path": "/name", "value": "anuran" },
                    { "op": "add", "path": "/position", "value": "NodeJS Developer" }
                  ])
                  let bdy={
                    patch:patchString
                  }

                chai.request(app)
                    .patch('/api/patch')
                    .set('token',tokenForToday)
                    .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
                    .send(bdy)
                    .end((err, res) => {
                      console.log(res.body);
                        res.should.have.status(422);
                        res.body.should.have.property('success').eql(false);
                      done();
                    });
                });
              })

              /**
               * Test /patch with invalid patch object
               */
               describe('/PATCH patch',()=>{
                 it('it should return false success', (done) => {
                   const dataString=JSON.stringify({
                           name: "dante",
                           age: "22"
                   });
                   const patchString=JSON.stringify([
                     { "op": "INVALID", "path": "/name", "value": "anuran" },
                     { "op": "add", "path": "/position", "value": "NodeJS Developer" }
                   ])
                   let bdy={
                     data:dataString,
                     patch:patchString
                   }

                 chai.request(app)
                     .patch('/api/patch')
                     .set('token',tokenForToday)
                     .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
                     .send(bdy)
                     .end((err, res) => {
                       console.log(res.body);
                         res.should.have.status(200);
                         res.body.should.have.property('success').eql(false);
                       done();
                     });
                 });
               })
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cb-assignment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000 --exit"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
    "easyimage": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "jsonpatch": "^3.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.1",
    "mocha": "^5.0.0",
    "node-image-resize": "0.0.2",
    "request": "^2.83.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5"
  }
}
```

i am running it from command line with this command:

**sudo ./node_modules/istanbul cover ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha**

Comment: In your test script I only see mocha and not istanbul/coverage ?

Comment: I am running istanbul from terminal like istanbul cover ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha

Comment: Note that with my first answer it should generate the full repport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my node.js (typescript) project I use this kind of script for tests + coverage :

```
"test": npm-run-all --parallel build:watch cross-env DOTENV_FILE=.env.test nodemon -e ts --exec mocha build/**/unit/**/*.spec.js --recursive --inspect --watch --reporter spec --bail
```

Start it simply with `npm run test`

EDIT :

For istanbul :

Step 1 - Run your server under istanbul

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover --handle-sigint  server.js
```

Step 2 -  Run your tests, no need to run under istanbul

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha  -R spec ./.instrument/test/** --recursive
```

The full report is under `coverage/lcov-report/index.html`

Comment: not working. with this even one of my test case is failing as I think chai-http is trying to connect to the server which I already ran with istanbul which in turn is giving port already in use error.

Comment: sorry, it generated the coverage after stopping the server. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the --exit flag after your coverage script